# TFS plugin for intellij invalid port error

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, tfs, connection, port

I'm using the plugin of Team Foundation Server for Intellij. When i try to share the project on TFS on a server with port different from 8080, an 'Invalid Port number' is reported in the error box without the possibility to go on  with the connection. 
Any Idea on how to proceed with the connection to the server?
[image: The example of a port different from 8080]

[image: The result when pressing OK button]

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by Dmitriy Smirnov's workaround? we have to specify the port number to add the TFS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just type in the full URL to the first field. So instead `myServerIP`, type `http://myServerIp:8090/tfs`

BTW, seems you are using third-party plugin for TFS integration. You could report the issue to author at https://intellijtfsplugin.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Also, you could try using JetBrains TFS integration plugin, or the one provided by Microsoft: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-visual-studio-team-services

Comment: This solves the problem. I'm trying with another plugin having encountered other problem due to url redirection Just after passing this step